# Load function after another function is run in JQuery

Tags: jquery

When loading a html page using JQuery load, I also need to call another function after the html has been loaded in a div. Here is the code i am using.

```
    $("#div").load("page.html", $('#file1').css('background','black'));
```

What happens is when the div is re-loaded it also removes the background color even though the code that changes the color is after the load. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing either an anonymous function or a function reference on the callback (the second argument).

```
$("#div").load("page.html", function(){
    $('#file1').css('background','black');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function

Comment: The reason for this is that unless you supply something that is a function as the second argument to load(), jQuery will try to send it as data to your url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback for this

sample from jquery

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.'); // this executes after the load 
});
```